# Laravel getting value from another table

Tags: laravel

I'm encountering an issue when trying to pass data from a Driver model to a Blade template in Laravel. Here's my setup:

```
public function index()
{
    // Retrieve the driver information based on the user's ID
    $driver = Driver::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

    return view('driver-dashboard', compact('driver'));
}
```

models

```
class User extends AuthenticatableUser implements Authenticatable
{
    // ...
    
    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Driver::class);
    }

    // Define common methods and attributes here
}

class Driver extends User
{
    // ...
    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
    
    // Additional methods specific to the Driver model
}
```

Blade Template

```
<div class="mb-6">
    <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold mb-2">Driver Information</h3>
    <!-- Display driver's name and profile picture -->
    <div>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</div>
    <img src="images/offers/{{ Auth::user()->picture }}" alt="Profile Picture" class="w-20 rounded-lg mt-2">
    @if($driver)
        <div>{{ $driver->description }}</div>
        <div>{{ $driver->license_plate }}</div>
        <div>{{ $driver->vehicle_type }}</div>
    @else
        <div>No driver information found.</div>
    @endif
</div>
```

route

```
Route::get('/driver-dashboard', [RegisteredDriverController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware(['auth'])
    ->name('driver.dashboard');
```

The problem I'm facing is that the **`$driver`** variable seems to be undefined in the Blade template. I've checked that the controller is passing the **`$driver`** variable correctly, and the user accessing the route is authenticated. Additionally, the **`Driver`** model extends the **`User`** model, and the database schema seems to be set up correctly.

Any insights into why **`$driver`** might be undefined in the Blade template would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why does the Driver model extend user? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: its because actually i have 4 table admin passenger they just extending the attributes from user but driver adding some attributes like description lisence plate...

Comment: you probably have another action returning this view and not giving it the `driver` variable